# Transfer data from VTK to SimpleITK and back

Tags: simpleitk

I have a VC++ app that use vtkDICOMReader to load CT data and rendering a volume.

After rendering the volume, I I have imported data from **VTK** into **SimpleITK**. Here is the code:

```
////  **importing data from VTK to SimpleITK**  ///////////////////////////////////
int* nDim =  **m_pDICOMReader** ->GetOutput()->GetDimensions();
TRACE(">>>>%d|%d|%d\n", nDim[0], nDim[1], nDim[2]); //  **result: >>>>512|512|102**
uint8_t* in = new uint8_t[nDim[0] * nDim[1] * nDim[2]];
double* dSpacing =  **m_pDICOMReader** ->GetOutput()->GetSpacing();
std::vector<double> spacing;
spacing.push_back(dSpacing[0]);
spacing.push_back(dSpacing[1]);
spacing.push_back(dSpacing[2]);
importer.SetSpacing(spacing);
double* dOrigin =  **m_pDICOMReader** ->GetOutput()->GetOrigin();
std::vector<double> origin;
origin.push_back(dOrigin[0]);
origin.push_back(dOrigin[1]);
origin.push_back(dOrigin[2]);
importer.SetOrigin(origin);
std::vector<unsigned int> size;
size.push_back((unsigned int)nDim[0]);
size.push_back((unsigned int)nDim[1]);
size.push_back((unsigned int)nDim[2]);
importer.SetSize(size);
importer.SetBufferAsUInt8(in);
sitk::Image  **img**  = importer.Execute();
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

after this importing, I saved the image on HDD:

```
sitk::Image img = importer.Execute();
img = sitk::GrayscaleErode(img, 10);
sitk::WriteImage(img, _T("D:\\Tempx\\TestSimpleITK.png"));
```

A simple black image ... I feel I didn't understood something here ... what can I know for sure if the transfer from VTK to SimpleITK is work correctly ?

Comment: Print out your extent array.  I'm pretty sure that isn't right. The values should be: 0, 511, 0, 511, 0, 43.

Comment: I updated the post ... please tell me if is ok now. Thank you Dave.

Comment: It looks good.  Does it work correctly?

Comment: Is working but I don't know if is working correctly. How I tried: I have converted from VTK to SimpleITK / sitk::Image img = importer.Execute(); / img = sitk::GrayscaleErode(img, 10); / convert SimpleITK to VTK ... the color volume rendered with VTK before this attempt is the same ...

Comment: And I answered so lately because this attempt takes more than 3 hours (debug mode) ... Release I didn't tried.

Comment: Can you suggest me a SimpleITK test in order to see if I done the conversion correctly ?

Comment: Write the image out as a file and look at it?  You should re-compile in Release mode.  It's going to be orders of magnitude faster than Debug.

Comment: I'll come back when II'll solve the link error when I add the line: sitk::WriteImage(img, _T("D:\\Tempx\\TestSimpleITK.png"));

Comment: The link error: itkgdcmMSFF-5.1.lib(gdcmUIDGenerator.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_UuidCreate referenced in function "protected: static bool __cdecl gdcm::UIDGenerator::GenerateUUID(unsigned char *)" (?GenerateUUID@UIDGenerator@gdcm@@KA_NPEAE@Z)

Comment: I have solved all errors. I've updated my first post.

Comment: your image is color.  I'm not sure grayscale erode works on a color image.